# set value in the droplink field

Tags: sitecore

How do I assign values in a droplink through coding?

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item PriceBookHome = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Administration/Price Books/Clarisonic-us-retail");
string currency = "INR";
string currenySource = PriceBookHome.Fields["Currency"].Source;
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item currenyDictSource = master.GetItem(currenySource);

foreach (Item im in currenyDictSource.GetChildren())
{

    if (im.Fields["Key"].Value == currency)
    {

        PriceBookHome.Editing.BeginEdit();
        PriceBookHome.Fields["Currency"].SetValue(im.DisplayName, true);
        PriceBookHome.Editing.EndEdit();
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error on the droplink after insertion: "This field contains a value that is not in the selection list"

Error I am getting as follows:

[image]

droplink source[Currency path as given source in droplink]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the ID of the currency item as value, not the name.

```
PriceBookHome.Fields["Currency"] = im.ID.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Need to do a little bit change and it works.
PriceBookHome.Fields["Currency"].Value = i.ID.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because you're storing a string (the displayname) in the field.  
As Ruud says, you can put the ID in, or do something like this:

```
PriceBookHome.Editing.BeginEdit();
var field = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ReferenceField)PriceBookHome.Fields["Currency"];
field.TargetItem = im;
PriceBookHome.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: it's read only.cannot assign value - am getting message like this whenever i tried your code.Ruud van Falier code works as expected.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. You can probably use the Relink or UpdateLink methods though, but that just complicates things I'd say. Using the solution Ruud provided is a lot easier :-)